# Is there any way to restrict multi-address shipping to certain customer groups?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, delivery

Long-time reader first-time poster here!

We have multi-address shipping enabled on our Magento store, but we want to limit its use to only certain customer groups; or, more specifically, we would like to exclude certain groups from using multi-address shipping.

Is this possible either with or without an extension? I have found some great shipping restriction extensions, but nothing dealing with multi-address shipping.

Thanks in advance!
Andre

Answer (score 0):

Andre - In Magento 1.9, I do not believe it is possible to limit multi-address shipping by customer groups (without using a third party extension or developing this functionality as an extension).

You can turn off multi-address shipping for all users, but it's not a default setting in Magento 1.9 to do this by customer group.

You can adjust this setting here:

System --> Configuration --> Sales --> Shipping Settings:

[image: Adjust ability to ship to multiple locations]

I hope this helps!